# Quick link to duplicates on search

Tags: discussion

Would it be useful if questions that are marked as duplicate had a link to the duplicate post on the search results?  So the user didn't have to go into the post before clicking the link to go to the duplicate?

Something potentially like:
[image]

Comment: *How* would it be useful to see two links - one now very much smaller than the other - as opposed to *one* link so that the searcher could derive context and meaning from why this was marked as a dupe to begin with?

Comment: The size of the links are simply what they were from my screen shots and splicing together a quick image.  Whatever the format, the idea is asking if others thought it would be useful.  I could potentially see someone searching about an issue they are having and multiple results could come back.  If a few of those results were the same duplicate, they might choose to go straight to the duplicate to see what's up.

Answer (score 1):

A picture in this context might be worth a thousands words, so let's try it.

[image]

I use a plugin called [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en), which allows me to see all of the [accessibility-compliant] clickable elements of a part of a page.  If I invoke this plugin, there are six total engagement points.  Add a seventh and there's already quite a lot of stuff going on with this view, which is less than desirable.

Additionally, you as a sighted person have the privilege of being able to understand *somewhat* intuitively from reading the text why the link to another question would appear there.  If you were listening to a screen reader try to parse that, it'd sound horrible since there's no sentence flow or structure to why that link is present.

I don't know if Stack Overflow makes a very conscious effort to support a11y - programming in certain respects can be a very visually demanding job - but it would make a lot of sense if they adhered to *some* standards when it comes to the website at large.  Adding more links in a very small space doesn't sound accessible in my mind, and I worry for those who rely on screen readers who would need, essentially, retraining on how to use the site.

Comment: From a screen reader perspective, would you find it more useful then if it appeared after the tags, or some where, and had a leading label of "Previously Answered" or something that the screen readers could capture which could make it apparent what the following link is about?

Comment: @Taplar:  That question *really* is better aimed at someone who is vision-impaired and is using the site.  I'm a humble developer who's been burned by a11y requirements before, and I have long since accepted that I have had these eyes for far too long to listen to web pages *and* not be somehow biased.  By and large, I'm throwing a *massive* wrench in your plans.  Worth thinking about, IMO.

Comment: That's cool.  It's why I asked the question, :)

Comment: Would you like to provide a link to the source of introductory information on a11y you personally consider most suited? I think for this it is appropriate to go by your personal opinion, it is the reason I want you to link on top of the use of a search engine I am about to do.